# Use variable names in select clause, need them to act like column name - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
T (Mon varchar(3));

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Y');
```

Case 1:

```
DECLARE @day varchar(3) = 'Mon'

SELECT Mon 
FROM T;  --result : Y (no problem)
```

Case 2:

```
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(3) = 'Mon'

SELECT @day 
FROM T; --result : Mon
```

If I want to get result `Y` in second case, how can I do that without re-designing the solution completely.

Comment: Can you use `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: Any alternative way other than Dynamic SQL ?

Comment: Not that I can immediately think of

Comment: Could you let me know if you get any idea on that

Comment: As nice as the answers are, can you guarantee no spaces or special characters may be used? Encapsulate variable with QUOTENAME(@variable, '[]')

Comment: But still not working @clifton_h

Comment: Need more info, really, but you concat the function using a '+' operator: N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@Col) + ' FROM TABLE'

Comment: I did like this :                                                                                          sqlCommand = 'SELECT day=' + day + ' FROM SectionMeeting WHERE AcademicTerm=academicTerm AND SectionID=sectionID AND MeetingSeq=meetingSeq'
EXECUTE sp_executesql sqlCommand, N'academicTerm nvarchar(75), sectionID nvarchar(75), meetingSeq int, day varchar(75) OUTPUT', academicTerm = academicTerm,
sectionID = sectionID,
meetingSeq = meetingSeq,
day = day OUTPUT; its working fine.

Comment: I see, is this for a Report? Just remember not to actually allow the user to write the query. [MSDN - Write Secure Dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669091(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: When we click on some button, that will call this procedure, so application will fetch and send the i/p parameters to procedure. But I will look into MSDN - Write Secure Dynamic SQL link. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
exec('select '+@day+' from #T;')
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you. Suppose If I need the result back into some variable without directly printing. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign this @day variable using this command.
and dont forget to use "top 1" to limit only 1 row data to get.
SELECT top 1 @day = Mon FROM T;

then You can use @day in other queries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating your question, I appreciate the simplicity.

`EXECUTE`/`EXEC` is a simple way of creating your script, allowing you to piece-meal the strings in variables and can be used with `VARCHAR`. Keep in mind that both `EXEC` and `sp_executesql` are not executed until runtime, so it will not be able to utilize cached query plans effectively or at all.

```
CREATE TABLE #Example   (
    Class_Type  VARCHAR(2)      NOT NULL
  , Mary        INT             NULL
  , Harry       VARCHAR(100)    NULL
  , Larry       XML             NULL
  , Sorry       NVARCHAR(100)   NULL )
INSERT INTO #Example (Class_Type, Mary, Harry, Larry, Sorry)
VALUES ('A', 250, 'Apples', CAST('<List><Class Professor="Harry">1</Class><Books>3</Books></List>' AS XML), N'Angelina')
     , ('A', 300, 'Pineapples', CAST('<List><Class Professor="Larry">1</Class><Books>3</Books></List>' AS XML), N'Prince Charles')
     , ('B', 15,  'Cucumbers',  CAST('<List><Class Professor="Sarry">2</Class><Books>5</Books></List>' AS XML), N'Larry Cable')
GO
```

**Here we use the `EXECUTE`/`EXEC` Method:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.USP_MyQuery (@Column NVARCHAR(255) )
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = ' FROM #Example WHERE Class_Type = ''' + 'A' + ''''
SET @Column = RTRIM(LTRIM(@Column));
    IF @Column IN (N'Mary', N'Harry', N'Larry', N'Sorry')
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@Column, '[]') + @SQL;
            EXEC (@SQL)
        END
    ELSE PRINT 'Check your spelling. Input does not match any existing columns'
END
GO
EXEC dbo.USP_MyQuery @Column = 'Mary'
```

`sp_executesql` is arguably the better method. Because the system procedure can paramertizes the **entire** statement (free from `SQL Injection`), `SQL Server` can reuse cached plans on the second query! For performance, safety, reability reasons and more, it is the preferred method of Dynamic SQL statements (*when possible*). **However, note that all strings passed through must be in `UNICODE` format (`NVARCHAR`)**

**Here we use the `sp_executesql` system procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.USP_MyQuery (@Column NVARCHAR(255) )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + 
           ' FROM #Example WHERE Class_Type = ''' + 'A' + ''''

SET @Column = RTRIM(LTRIM(@Column))
IF @Column IN (N'Mary', N'Harry', N'Larry', N'Sorry')
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @SQL
    END
ELSE PRINT 'Check your spelling. Input does not match any existing columns'
END
EXEC dbo.USP_MyQuery @Column = 'Mary'
```

Not so hard, no? Likely you may want to use more testing and take advantage of functions like `REPLACE()` for making your query robust from human error.

Lastly, remember that `QUOTENAME()` removes system names identifiers, and instead replaces the string with a deliminator (`'[]'` is the default setting)

Comment: Thank you. I did it by using dynamic sql (sp_executesql only)